# User cannot enter his group's directory despite the directory having the correct permissions and the user being in the proper group

Tags: linux, permissions, centos7, centos6

I have a directory called `/workspace` that looks like this:

`[root@machine workspace]# ls -al`
`total 7`
`drwxr-s---.  7 root workspace 4651468242 Nov 16 14:41 .`
`dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root root            4096 Nov 15 11:36 ..`
(I left out its subdirectories. You can see that `/workspace` belongs to the group `workspace`)

Then there's a user `yang` whose `id` is as follows:
`[root@machine workspace]# id yang`
`uid=563(yang) gid=1701(yang) groups=1701(yang),1044(workspace)`
This should allow him to enter `/workspace` but in reality he couldn't:
`[root@machine workspace]# su - yang`
`Last login: Mon Nov 22 10:05:41 CST 2021 on pts/46`
`[yang@machine ~]$ cd /workspace/`
`-bash: cd: /workspace/: Permission denied`
However of all users in the group `workspace`, he's the only one with this problem. Other users can access `/workspace` just fine, for example:
`[root@machine workspace]# id zhao`
`uid=651(zhao) gid=651(zhao) groups=651(zhao),1044(workspace)`
`[root@machine workspace]# su - zhao`
`Last login: Mon Nov 22 10:13:27 CST 2021 on pts/103`
`[zhao@machine ~]$ cd /workspace/`
`[zhao@machine workspace]$`
More details here:
`[yang@machine ~]$ id`
`uid=563(yang) gid=1701(yang) groups=1701(yang),1044(workspace) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`

`[zhao@machine ~]$ id`
`uid=651(zhao) gid=651(zhao) groups=651(zhao),1044(workspace) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`
The frustrating issue is encountered on both CentOS 6.9 and 7.9. Can anybody help me with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after a colleague suggested me that there might be an upper limit for supplementary groups, I doubled checked and found that `/workspace` is on an `nfs` drive with the command `df -hT`, and according to [RFC5531](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5531), when using AUTH_SYS authentication, the default maximum number of group IDs is 16. I found a [guide from NetApp](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1610208/html/GUID-1D3D018C-DF37-4C87-A789-58526A46B1A9.html) teaching you how to change the default limit. While in practice the method should differ between different vendors, it can nevertheless give you an overall idea.

Another lesson is to never leave out anything when asking questions. As it turned out, `yang` belonged to more than 16 groups while most other users didn't exceed that number. I left out the other groups thinking they were too long, too obtrusive, but in the end, they turned out to be the problem.